# 2009 Nissan Murano Negative Battery Terminal

Tags: battery, nissan, murano

Mechanics, I am in the process of getting our Murano ready to sell.  Is there any advise to how I can ensure the NEGATIVE terminal is more secure???  I have it as tight as it will tighten, but it still is not tight enough.  Any suggestions.

Comment: Others have used shims made of copper sheet or wire, for example -https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/69288/why-put-copper-in-between-battery-contacts-and-clamps/69290#69290